# Excel underline only to cell width (cell's text goes in to other cells)

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a normal excel which has certain cell's texts which are greater than it's width and overflows to the next cell (the  overflown cells are empty).
IE : Cell A1 has text that goes in to cell A2.

If I try to underline all the text in A1, the underline goes as far as the width of the cell.
I am not trying to underline using borders either.
I am trying with the standard U (underline) symbol.[image]

If you see the red circled ones above the, I belive you guys can understand the issue.
I need the underline to work on all cells that overflow to the other texts.

I have considered using borders as an alternative, but in some cases, the text does not cover the entire overflown text which makes the border fail at working as an underline.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour as my Excel 2010 underlines the entire text ( text in cell A1 + overflown part ). But my guess is to refresh the sheet by activating another one and then back to original. I think this question is more suitable for [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: second above - cannot reproduce that behaviour

Comment: thank you for trying guys.It was an underline issue that I didn't even know that existed. Issue sorted. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its the problem with selection of "single accounting" option. Instead of "Single" you might have selected "single accounting" in underline option mistakenly.

See the below screenshots for comparision.

Hope this helps

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have not accidentally set the cell border rather than the text property.